# rsync is copying all files

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-14.04

I have 3 servers, two of which share a drive with nfs, and other server and nfs driver share data with rsync. changes made on 3rd server transfered to nfs drive via rsync. earlier it was working fine,for some reason we had to change both server with nfs shared drive. now every time we perform rsync, it copies all data.

rsync command which is used is given below.

> rsync -rzv  -e "ssh -p2221 -i /home/ubuntu/server.pem"  /file/data/folder/  ubuntu@x.x.x.x:/file/data/folder

Comment: Did you check date, time and timezone?

Comment: yes i did , both are in same time zone

Comment: So the time is exactly the same on both machines?

Comment: yes, is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Normally rsync works fine when the server times are synchronized.